# what file needed to open exe in other computer mvcp100d needed

Tags: c++

I created small aplication, copied exe from debug, copied textures, fonts in same folder as my exe is. In my computer, with visual studio installed i dont have any problem with running this, but on other computer i can't run this application, beacause of mvcp100d.dll(system don't see this). Is there any possibility, to run this exe in any other cumpter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need the debug version, I would build in release mode.  Not only can that be distributed, it's usually faster also.  It doesn't seem to me that you are doing anything with debugging that application.

Answer (score 6):

*To prepare a computer to test the debug version of an application that is built with Visual C++, you have to deploy debug versions of the Visual C++ library DLLs that the application depends on.* -from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618.aspx

NOTE: Debug versions of MSVC runtime are **not** redistributable.